# Product of two differentials

Tags: calculus

Is the product of two differentials exactly equal to $0$ or do we approximate it to $0$?

Like $\operatorname d x\cdot \operatorname d y$? I was solving a physics question and they took $\operatorname d V \cdot \operatorname d x = 0$. So did they approximated or is it exactly equal to $0$.

Comment: A product is zero when one of the factors is zero.

Comment: In general $dxdy\ne0$, but maybe we can explain the reasoning behind $dVdx=0$ if you showed us how it came up. If for example $dV=dxdydz$, then $dx^2=0$ would explain it.

Comment: @J.G. It was that, we were supposed to multiply (V+dV)(x+dx) = Vx + Vdx + xdV + dVdx. And so we took dVdx = 0.

Comment: [Ah](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0):

So this question is about a proof of the product rule:$$\begin{align}(V+dV)(x+dx)-Vx&=(V+dV)dx+xdV\\\implies\lim_{dt\to0}\frac{(V+dV)(x+dx)-Vx}{dt}&=\left(V+\lim_{dt\to0}dV\right)\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dV}{dt}\\&=V\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dV}{dt}.\end{align}$$So the issue here is that $dVdx\propto dt^2$ is negligible after division by $dt$, so doesn't survive in the derivative-calculating limit.